# Changing spotLight.shadowCameraFov 'on the fly'

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to change shadowCameraFov property of spot light object using onChange method, here is the code:

```
    gui.add(controls, 'spotCameraFov', 30, 270).onChange( function (e) {
            spotLight.shadowCameraFov = e;
            console.log(e);
    });
```

I can see that the value is changing ( from the console.log ), but it actually cause no effect on the spot light shadowCameraFov. Any suggestion on how can I make it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern you need to follow:

```
gui.add( controls, 'shadowCameraFov', 30, 120 ).onChange( function() {

    spotLight.shadowCameraFov = controls.shadowCameraFov;
    spotLight.shadowCamera.fov = spotLight.shadowCameraFov;
    spotLight.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();

});
```

You can see a live example here: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shading_physical.html. Controls are on the top right.

three.js r.62

Comment: Thank you. That was the case. Could you explain me why it works for the first time - when you define new spot light you can just write spotLight.shadowCameraFov = x and it will be set to this value and when you update this value you have to make steps mentioned in your answer ?

Comment: `ShadowMapPlugin.js` handles these steps in the first call. If you make parameter changes, you need to repeat the same steps manually. Study the source code for more information.